# Access properties of base class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, inheritance

I have this class:

```
public class CameraWindow : PictureBox
```

Can i somehow access the `Image` property from inside of the class?

And can i access the Events? like `onload`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just use them... all public and protected members are directly accessible.

Comment: Thanks, i tried `this.Image` lol now i just removed the `this` and it works, but can you show me an example for `Load` event ?

Comment: Hm, not sure I get you. `Load()` is a method. There are only `LoadCompleted` and `LoadProgressChanged` events which habe "load" in the name. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The `LoadCompleted` is what i need, and this event will shoot after my constructor or when the PictureBox is loaded on the form?

Comment: Neither... it's a bit more complex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
public class CameraWindow : PictureBox
{
    void Test()
    {
        this.Image; // or just Image
    }
}

public class CameraWindow : PictureBox
{
    public override object Image
    {
        { get { return base.Image; } }// note base
    }
}
```

Comment: the `Image` property is not virtual, this `override` is not valid here.

Comment: @Lucero: In case of `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`, you're of course right. I just wanted to how how can it be in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with Windows Forms or similar? In that case the event is probably Load, and you can tie it up with something like Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);

The prompts will help you generate an event handler.

Comment: Yes it's WinForms but it's nor a form, it's a PictureBox control :)